# Win32 DLL plugin safety

Tags: c, winapi, dll, plugins

In Win32/64 I plan on offering a directory where [all files] plugins can be loaded from DLL's. The application will queue each DLL in the directory with a structure pointer where the DLL will inform the application how it extends the main application and verify that it's indeed a plugin.

Is there any way I can prevent each DLL call inquiry from crashing the application or hijacking execution? There's really no way I can verify if the DLLs will have malicious intent. I would like to kill the call if it's not assigning valid data to the inquiry call's structure, not returning in a timely manner, or starts to make system calls (shouldn't be necessary for a simple inquiry). Seems like there's no reliable way to do this. Perhaps I could limit the call's system permissions? Where should I look?

Comment: I've done something similar in the past. The most effective way is to digitally sign your valid DLL files and check for that signature in your application before loading the DLL.

Comment: Who will write the plugins? You?

Comment: Anyone who feels like it. I've written a convenience application to access different functionality of my PC from the couch using a remote or a keyboard. If it's useful I will supply it for free on the internet, extendable thru plugins. I may write some of the plugins, but it's mainly an extensibility feature for anyone else who wants to add features.

Comment: If the user installs a malicious plugin, Game Over.  There's **nothing** you can realistically do to prevent that.  It's no different from the user installing a malicious application.

Comment: So I guess I'm looking at some kind of scripting capability. That's a lot of work, but it would avoid the DLL problem.

Comment: Load the plugins from a sandbox.exe to isolate the process from your own and run the probe in the context of a user with few rights.

Comment: @Chris, there's a [paper here](http://theinvisiblethings.blogspot.co.nz/2014/01/shattering-myths-of-windows-security.html) about the limitations of that approach.  It's better than nothing, but it doesn't make it safe.